# Web Services in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services

I have many projects setup in eclipse.  One of these projects is a Web Service Client Project.  When I start tomcat using the Start Tomcat plugin in eclipse Juno, my Web Service project is not running. I get a 404 http error. However, using the Server tab in eclipse (on creating my web services project, a Server project is also created), if I start Server, my Web Service Projects runs corectly.

I am of the view therefore that Web Services projects must be started using the Server->Start option and not Start Tomcat using the plugin.

I am new to Web services.  Can anyone share some information on this, and how perhaps I can get the Web Services project to run using the Tomcat plugin.

Regards

Fyzal

Answer (score 0):

did you add the Web Service project on the Server ? Right Click on Webservice Project and Run on Server OR Right Click on the Server and "Add or Remove" Resource

Comment: Yes, the web services is added to the server; the real issue is that when tomcat plugin is started, the web services client project does not run, only when the server is started.  But when the server is started, none of the other projects run, as after the server is started, there is a clash of ports if you attempt to start tomcat.  What I need is to be able to start tomcat from the plugin and get the web services client app to run also.